# The time complexity of O(nⁿ) and O(n!)

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Get the complexity order of below

```
O(1), O(log(n)), O(n⋅log(n)),O(n), O(n²), O(2ⁿ), O(n!), O(nⁿ), O(n³).
```

The order should be below:

```
O(1) < O(log(n)) < O(n) < O(n log n) < O(n²) < O(n³) < O(2ⁿ) < O(nⁿ) < O(n!)
```

In my opinion,  nⁿ = n⋅n⋅n⋅...
       however,  `n! = n(n-1)(n-2).....` so `O(n!) < O(nⁿ)`

However, another friend said `O(nⁿ) < O(n!)`,

because  `n! = sqrt( 2πn ) ⋅ (n/e)ⁿ`

I dont know how to get this, please explain more about this.

Comment: Hello Jongware, it is not homework, I am practicing some interview questions.

Comment: Chris, I modified the question, do you think which has higher complexity? O(N^N) or O(N!)?

Comment: For those with mathematical backgrounds, you can compare by taking the limit of the ratio i.e. lim n -> inf (n! / n ^ n)

Answer (score 2):

The formula `n! ≈ sqrt( 2πn ) ⋅ (n/e)ⁿ` is called the [Stirlings approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).
But this shows also `O(n!) < O(nⁿ)`, if you know that `sqrt(n)` grows much slower than `(1/e)ⁿ` falls (for growing `n`). (`limn → ∞ sqrt(n) / eⁿ = 0`). So

```
O(n!) = O(sqrt(n) ⋅ (1/e)ⁿ ⋅ nⁿ) < O(nⁿ)
```

holdes, since `sqrt(n) ⋅ (1/e)ⁿ` gets much smaller than 1, in the order of `O((1/e)ⁿ)`.

But the formula is only an approximazation. As you mentioned:

```
nⁿ = n ⋅ n ⋅ ... ⋅ n   (n times)  
n! = n ⋅ (n-1) ⋅ ... ⋅ 2 ⋅ 1 
   < n ⋅ n ⋅ ... ⋅ n = nⁿ
```

This is enought to show that `O(n!) < O(nⁿ)`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets Assume N is = 4.

- If you call O(N!), the loop will iterate N! time for each loop. The 1st loop will be 1, the 2nd loop will be 1, 2 the 3rd loop will be 1, 2, 3 and the 4th loop will be 1, 2, 3, 4.
- So you have:
- 1
- 1, 2
- 1, 2, 3
- 1, 2, 3, 4
- And if you call O(N^N), the loop will iterate N times for each loop. 1st loop will be 1, 2, 3, 4 the 2nd loop will be 1, 2, 3, 4 the 3rd loop will be 1, 2, 3, 4 and the 4th loop will be 1, 2, 3, 4
- So you have:
- 1, 2, 3, 4
- 1, 2, 3, 4
- 1, 2, 3, 4
- 1, 2, 3, 4
- So you can see that O(N!) will terminate earlier than O(N^N) because it does not have to loop through to the end of the list for each iteration. Thus the time complexity O(N!) < O(N^N) or rather O(N!) is better than O(N^N).

Comment: Hey, Juniar, this is what I thought. However, the friend who claims O(N!) has higher complexity showed me this:  n! =sqrt(2pi*n)(n/e)^n, what confuses me is how to get formula.